# How to deal with cyrillic letters caused error (#REF) in worksheets (unicode VBA display and handling), in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to get data from a particular workbooks (there are couple of dozens of them, the looping part is working properly), but the code below does not work cause the worksheets are in Cyrillic, and they are giving the value '???????' to the `sheet As String` parameter. I would like to ask how to force to rename a workbook without opening it at all (without `Workbook.Open(WorkbookNum1)` as it would take quite a much time, in this case). Or how to modify this code to apply sheet index e.g.: `sheets(3)`?

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

    Dim arg As String

    'Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"

    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
    Exit Function

   End If

   'Create the argument
   arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
   Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
   'Execute an XLM macro
   GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

End Function


Sub TestGetValue()

    p = "c:\XLFiles\Budget"
    f = "Budget.xls"
    s = "Sheet1"
    a = "A1"

    MsgBox GetValue(p, f, s, a)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the workbooks and using the *Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3* **codenames** instead of the cyrillic worksheet names? Anything to do with VBA is very EN-US-centric so the worksheet codenames should be the standard defaults.

Comment: Even with the VBA to looping over with opening it and closeing it would take 10-15 min... and just couple of data is needed... on 2 sheets/workbook :/ They are identically organised but the amount of workbooks are big... :/

Comment: Hmmm... I would think that with the speed of modern computers there is very little that could take 10-15 minutes. Must be pretty calculation intensive.

Comment: VBA handles unicode very well, but the VBA Editor doesn't display unicode. My question is, are the sheet names the same in each book, or is there only a limited range of sheet names? If so I can help.

Comment: The sheet names are the same, but they are all in Cyrillic... and that cause the error...

Comment: If the sheets name in Latin or a number (or any variety of this) there is no problem at all, but if it is in Cyrillic the final value is ' #Ref ' (which caused by Cyrillic alphabet)

Comment: I've created an answer. I'm only worried about one thing: "ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)". Is that proc actually calling an Excel 4.0 macro or is it just an unfortunate name? (Relevant because Excel 4 is kinda ancient and probably doesn't do unicode).

Comment: Yes probably that might be the reason. But to be hones I couldn't find the proper way to take data from workbooks without Opening it. (To be honest I would not say I'm really professional yet in VBA, but hopefully one time :) And thank you very much ones again it was a really good help ;) !!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBA handles unicode well, but the VBA Editor doesn't display it. This can make unicode hard to work with in VBA if you're not used to it.

When first faced with the need to work with unicode (mostly people using random squiggles for cute text effects, but also a whole Russian website) I worked around this by placing the unicode strings in a worksheet (worksheets display unicode just fine), then set up my variables by pulling their values from the worksheet.

So, set up a worksheet called, say "UniSrc" (the name can be anything), with path, file, sheet, and address in columns A to D. Copy and paste the unicode sheet names in column C.

Here is your test procedure, modified to work this way:

```
Sub TestGetValue()
    dim rowNow as long, wks as excel.worksheet
    dim p as string, f as string, s as string, a as string

    rowNow = 2 ' assuming row 1 is a header
    set wks = thisworkbook.sheets("UniSrc")
    with wks
        p = .cells(rowNow, 1) ' path
        f = .cells(rowNow, 2) ' file name
        s = .cells(rowNow, 3) ' unicode name of sheet sought
        a = .cells(rowNow, 4) ' cell address sought
    end with

    MsgBox GetValue(p, f, s, a)
End Sub
```

Now we need to update your GetValue function:

```
Function GetValue(sPath as string, sFile as string, sSheet as string, sAddress as string) as variant
    Dim arg As String, vTmp as variant

    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"
    If Dir(sPath & sFile) = "" Then ' Make sure the file exists
        vTmp = "File Not Found"
    else ' Create the argument
        arg = "'" & sPath & "[" & sFile & "]" & sSheet & "'!" & _
        Range(sAddress).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
        'Execute an XLM macro
        vTmp = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
    End If
    GetValue = vTmp
End Function
```

See how you go. I'm on my tablet so I've written this off the top of my head and can't test it, but the essentials are there.

Comment: Winterknell, you are genius... I spent all my day to figuring it out, how to solve this issue, and basically nothing. Yes its working! Thank you very much ;) !!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You're welcome, and thanks for the tick.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode characters in VBA can be hard coded as a sequence of `ChrW` function concatenations.

```
MsgBox ChrW(1044) & ChrW(1040) ' "ДА"
```

To get the [unicode code points](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0414/index.htm), you can for example put the sheet name in `A1` and try something like:

```
Dim b() As Byte, i As Long, a As Long
b = [A1].Text ' converts the string to byte array (2 or 4 bytes per character)

For i = 1 To UBound(b) Step 2            ' 2 bytes per Unicode codepoint
    a = b(i)
    a = a * 256 + b(i - 1) 
    Debug.Print " & AscW(" & a & ")";
Next
```

Comment: Hello Slai,
Honestly, I think I just partially understood you :S. It's not really clear to me why you are defining `b() As Byte` and assigning an array to it, it is causing **Type mismatch error**. But as I understand you are suggesting to decode the Russian words to Unicode and then run the code as it is?!

Comment: ah sorry about that @svi, I can't test the code this week. It is much more likely that I misunderstood, but from what I understand, when for example you paste the Unicode characters in the VBA editor, they show up as ??. A way around that can be to use ChrW (I am assuming the first code sample works?). The byte array is a hack to get the bytes from a string.

Comment: The code part is still not really clear to me Slai, but the Idea of `ChrW(....)` is really useful in general, in some other cases was really helpful Thanks ;) (Every day we can learn something that we thought is impossible ;) )